# Best way to make many logical comparisons in the if clause of a list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I want to get a list of all the natural numbers between 1 - 1000 that are either multiples of 3 OR 5.

I tried with a list comprehension:

```
   [x for x in range(1, 1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 ==0]
```

Which leads to the question: 
Is there a nice way of stringing together many logical comparisons in the if clause of a list comprehension in Python?

Comment: What part of it doesn't work? Seems to work just fine..

Comment: As a nit-picky side note, this isn't an `if statement`, it's an `if clause`. Python doesn't have statements inside expressions.

Comment: updated to reflect both of your comments. many thanks - nitpicky is fine so long as you're right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is your real question (emphasis added):

> Is there a nice way of stringing together ***many*** logical comparisons in the if statement of a list comprehension in Python?

Your existing code works fine for two comparisons, but what if you had 30 of them?

The way to do that is to factor out the comparisons so you can write a comprehension over them, then pass that to the `all` or `any` function.

For example, if your code looked like this:

```
[x for x in range(1, 1000) 
 if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0 or x % 7 == 0 or x % 11 == 0
 or x % 13 == 0 or x % 17 == 0 or x % 19 == 0 or x % 23 == 0]
```

… that would be a huge mess. But you can write it as:

```
[x for x in range(1, 1000) 
 if any(x % i == 0 for i in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23)]
```

Or, of course, you can factor that out into a function, which gives you a chance to name things:

```
primes529 = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23)

def composite529(x):
    return any(x % i == 0 for i in primes529)

[x for x in range(1, 1000) if composite529(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works exactly as written

```
[x for x in range(1, 1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 ==0]
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99,
 100, 102, 105, 108, 110, 111, 114, 115, 117, 120, 123, 125, 126, 129, 130, 132, 135, 138, 140, 141, 144, 145, 147, 150, 153, 155, 156, 159, 160, 162, 165, 168, 170, 171, 174, 175, 177, 180, 183, 185, 186, 189, 190, 192, 195, 198, 200,
 201, 204, 205, 207, 210, 213, 215, 216, 219, 220, 222, 225, 228, 230, 231, 234, 235, 237, 240, 243, 245, 246, 249, 250, 252, 255, 258, 260, 261, 264, 265, 267, 270, 273, 275, 276, 279, 280, 282, 285, 288, 290, 291, 294, 295, 297,
 300, 303, 305, 306, 309, 310, 312, 315, 318, 320, 321, 324, 325, 327, 330, 333, 335, 336, 339, 340, 342, 345, 348, 350, 351, 354, 355, 357, 360, 363, 365, 366, 369, 370, 372, 375, 378, 380, 381, 384, 385, 387, 390, 393, 395, 396, 399,
 400, 402, 405, 408, 410, 411, 414, 415, 417, 420, 423, 425, 426, 429, 430, 432, 435, 438, 440, 441, 444, 445, 447, 450, 453, 455, 456, 459, 460, 462, 465, 468, 470, 471, 474, 475, 477, 480, 483, 485, 486, 489, 490, 492, 495, 498,
 500, 501, 504, 505, 507, 510, 513, 515, 516, 519, 520, 522, 525, 528, 530, 531, 534, 535, 537, 540, 543, 545, 546, 549, 550, 552, 555, 558, 560, 561, 564, 565, 567, 570, 573, 575, 576, 579, 580, 582, 585, 588, 590, 591, 594, 595, 597,
 600, 603, 605, 606, 609, 610, 612, 615, 618, 620, 621, 624, 625, 627, 630, 633, 635, 636, 639, 640, 642, 645, 648, 650, 651, 654, 655, 657, 660, 663, 665, 666, 669, 670, 672, 675, 678, 680, 681, 684, 685, 687, 690, 693, 695, 696, 699,
 700, 702, 705, 708, 710, 711, 714, 715, 717, 720, 723, 725, 726, 729, 730, 732, 735, 738, 740, 741, 744, 745, 747, 750, 753, 755, 756, 759, 760, 762, 765, 768, 770, 771, 774, 775, 777, 780, 783, 785, 786, 789, 790, 792, 795, 798,
 800, 801, 804, 805, 807, 810, 813, 815, 816, 819, 820, 822, 825, 828, 830, 831, 834, 835, 837, 840, 843, 845, 846, 849, 850, 852, 855, 858, 860, 861, 864, 865, 867, 870, 873, 875, 876, 879, 880, 882, 885, 888, 890, 891, 894, 895, 897,
 900, 903, 905, 906, 909, 910, 912, 915, 918, 920, 921, 924, 925, 927, 930, 933, 935, 936, 939, 940, 942, 945, 948, 950, 951, 954, 955, 957, 960, 963, 965, 966, 969, 970, 972, 975, 978, 980, 981, 984, 985, 987, 990, 993, 995, 996, 999]
```

If your question is "either multiples of 3 **XOR** 5" then you use the `^` operator

```
[x for x in range(1, 1000) if ((x % 3 == 0) ^ (x % 5 == 0))]

[3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 93, 95, 96, 99,
 100, 102, 108, 110, 111, 114, 115, 117, 123, 125, 126, 129, 130, 132, 138, 140, 141, 144, 145, 147, 153, 155, 156, 159, 160, 162, 168, 170, 171, 174, 175, 177, 183, 185, 186, 189, 190, 192, 198,
 200, 201, 204, 205, 207, 213, 215, 216, 219, 220, 222, 228, 230, 231, 234, 235, 237, 243, 245, 246, 249, 250, 252, 258, 260, 261, 264, 265, 267, 273, 275, 276, 279, 280, 282, 288, 290, 291, 294, 295, 297,
 303, 305, 306, 309, 310, 312, 318, 320, 321, 324, 325, 327, 333, 335, 336, 339, 340, 342, 348, 350, 351, 354, 355, 357, 363, 365, 366, 369, 370, 372, 378, 380, 381, 384, 385, 387, 393, 395, 396, 399,
 400, 402, 408, 410, 411, 414, 415, 417, 423, 425, 426, 429, 430, 432, 438, 440, 441, 444, 445, 447, 453, 455, 456, 459, 460, 462, 468, 470, 471, 474, 475, 477, 483, 485, 486, 489, 490, 492, 498,
 500, 501, 504, 505, 507, 513, 515, 516, 519, 520, 522, 528, 530, 531, 534, 535, 537, 543, 545, 546, 549, 550, 552, 558, 560, 561, 564, 565, 567, 573, 575, 576, 579, 580, 582, 588, 590, 591, 594, 595, 597,
 603, 605, 606, 609, 610, 612, 618, 620, 621, 624, 625, 627, 633, 635, 636, 639, 640, 642, 648, 650, 651, 654, 655, 657, 663, 665, 666, 669, 670, 672, 678, 680, 681, 684, 685, 687, 693, 695, 696, 699,
 700, 702, 708, 710, 711, 714, 715, 717, 723, 725, 726, 729, 730, 732, 738, 740, 741, 744, 745, 747, 753, 755, 756, 759, 760, 762, 768, 770, 771, 774, 775, 777, 783, 785, 786, 789, 790, 792, 798,
 800, 801, 804, 805, 807, 813, 815, 816, 819, 820, 822, 828, 830, 831, 834, 835, 837, 843, 845, 846, 849, 850, 852, 858, 860, 861, 864, 865, 867, 873, 875, 876, 879, 880, 882, 888, 890, 891, 894, 895, 897,
 903, 905, 906, 909, 910, 912, 918, 920, 921, 924, 925, 927, 933, 935, 936, 939, 940, 942, 948, 950, 951, 954, 955, 957, 963, 965, 966, 969, 970, 972, 978, 980, 981, 984, 985, 987, 993, 995, 996, 999]
```

Comment: Your second version doesn't work because you've added parentheses, and done so in the wrong places.

Comment: Why do you say that? The output seems correct to me.

Comment: OK, now it works. But what do you have parens around the whole condition? The internal ones are needed for disambiguating precedence, but the outer ones aren't doing anything, are they?

Comment: Well you got me nervous before, so I added extra to be safe! Extra parentheses never hurt anyone :)